# Button default content if image (from dynamic resource) is not available

Tags: c#, wpf, image, button, dynamicresource

In a UserControl, I want the buttons to show images (provided by dynamic resources). If the dynamic resource is not available / provided by the application, I want the button to show some default content.

My idea was to put the default content into a textblock that is located underneath the image and hide it (so it does not shine through) as long as the image source is null. But this condition does not seem to work if resolving the DynamicResource fails. What exactly would be the status of the image's source in that case?

```
<Button Command="{Binding DoSomethingCommand}">
  <Grid>
    <TextBlock Text="DefaultText" Visibility="Collapsed">
         <TextBlock.Style>
           <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Style.Triggers>
              <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=TestImage, Path=Source}" Value="{x:Null}">
                 <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"></Setter>
              </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
           </Style>
          </TextBlock.Style>
    </TextBlock>
    <Image x:Name="TestImage" Source="{DynamicResource SomeResource}" Stretch="None"/>
    </Grid>
  </Button>
```

What would be a proper solution?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: In the view part i.e in the UI side, how do you determine if the image is not available in the dynamic resource?

Comment: have you tried use [FallbackValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.fallbackvalue(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: FallbackValue is not available, since there is no "Binding".

Comment: @Sethu Bala: in my App.xaml I simply comment out the definition of the BitmapImage <BitmapImage x:Key="SomeResource" 
                   UriSource="pack://application:,,,/MyApp;component/assets/someImg.png" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    <Button Command="{Binding DoSomethingCommand}">
        <Grid>
            <TextBlock Text="DefaultText" />
            <Image x:Name="TestImage" Source="{DynamicResource SomeResource}" Stretch="None"/>
        </Grid>
    </Button>
```

The TextBlock will be hidden by the Image only when the resource lookup succeeds.

> The problem with this is, that the default content shines through if the image is showing and it does not cover the entire default content

What about this then?

```
    <Button Command="{Binding DoSomethingCommand}">
        <Grid>
            <Image x:Name="TestImage" Source="{DynamicResource SomeResource}" Stretch="None"/>
            <TextBlock Text="DefaultText">
                <TextBlock.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Source, ElementName=TestImage}" Value="{x:Null}">
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </TextBlock.Style>
            </TextBlock>
        </Grid>
    </Button>
```

Comment: The problem with this is, that the default content shines through if the image is showing and it does not cover the entire default content.

Comment: That is strange: adding the line <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" /> into the style does the trick. The order of TextBlock and Image in the Grid seems to be irrelevant. What is the difference to setting the Visibility directly in the TextBlock?

Comment: Local values take precedence over value set by styles: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230(v=vs.110).aspx